# Watin - How to set value of textarea (HTML editor)?

Tags: tinymce, textarea, watin

I'm trying to set the value of a textfield using the following code:

```
if (ie.TextField(Find.ById("testField")).Exists)
   ie.TextField(Find.ById("testField")).Value = "Test";
```

The code passes without raising an error, however the textfield is not filled with the value.

I get an exception when I execute the following line:

```
ie.TextField(Find.ById("testField")).Focus()
```

The textarea is a tiny_mce editor and one of the html  attributes is: `style="display: none;"...`

Any ideas how I can modify the value of such a field using Watin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First tinymce is not a textarea. tinymce hides your textarea on initialization and creates a contenteditable iframe which is then used to allow text editing, styling aso...
Second if you want to write the editors content back to the hidden textarea you may do this using 
`tinymce.get('testField').triggerSave();`.

Another way to set the value of your textarea is:
`tinymce.get('testField').getDocumentById('testField').value = 'new value';`

In case you want to write content directly to your tinymce editor you may choose on of the following

```
tinymce.get('testField').setContent('my_new_content'); // replaces the editors content
```

or

```
tinymce.get('testField').execCommand('mceInsertContent',false, 'my_content_to_be_added'); // adds the content at the carat postion
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I'm not quite sure what the "ed" means in ed.getDocumentById - how do I get this element?

For the other solutions: How do I get the tinymce object?

The "body" textarea cannot be changed using Watin.   
I can access the "body_ifr" IFrame (that's the element where the text is stored), using: ie.Frame(Find.ById("body_ifr")).Text; -- but I don't know how to modify the text?

Comment: The HTML for the editor looks like (I deleted the toolbar code):

<textarea id="body" name="body" style="width: 615px; height: 320px; display: none;"></textarea>  
<span class="mceEditor defaultSkin" id="body_parent">  
<table style="width: 615px; height: 320px;" class="mceLayout" id="body_tbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr class="mceFirst">           
</tr><tr><td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">  
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 276px;" src='javascript:""' id="body_ifr" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: i replaced the 'ed' with the proper editor object. The tinymce object should be a global object variable after tinymce got initialized

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to handle this using the Watin Eval function:

```
var js = "tinyMCE.get('body').setContent('" + bodyCont + "')";
var s = ie.Eval(js);
```

'`body`' needs to replaced with the id of the textarea that is hidden by tinymce - do a "view source" in your browser window to find this id.